# What's the meaure of the radius in the circle below?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: Calculate r in the figure (O is the center) R = 4 (Answer:$\sqrt{\frac{8}{3}}$)
[image]

My progress:

$\triangle AOT:\\
AT^2 = 4^2+4^2 \implies AT = 4\sqrt2$

Th Apollonius:

$\triangle AEB:\\
BE^2 +(4+r)^2 =2OE^2 + \frac{8^2}{2} \implies \\
BE^2+16+8r+r^2=2OE^2 +32\\
BE^2+2OE^2+8r+r^2 -16=0$

...???

[image]

Comment: Set up coordinate system, set up the 2 (or 3) equations, and you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

From point $ \small C$, drop perp $ \small CE$ to $ \small OD$ and $ \small CH$ to $ \small AB$.

$ \small OH = CE = \sqrt{OC^2 - OE^2} ~$.
Note $ \small OC = R-r, OE = R/2$ (as $OC = CD = R-r$).

Once you find $ \small OH$,

$ \small AC^2 = (AO+OH)^2 + CH^2$
$ \small \implies 2 AO \cdot OH = AC^2 - CH^2 - AO^2 - OH^2$.

Note $ \small CH = OE = R/2, AC = R + r, AO = R$

It does simplify quickly and you should get the relationship $R^2 = 6r^2$

Comment: Also, if you extend $DC$ and it intersects $AB$ at $G$ then you can apply Euclid's theorem in $\triangle ACG$ or $\triangle ADG$ (note $DG = 2 DC = 2(R-r)$ and $OG = 2 OH$. Very similar to above solution that I have proposed.

Answer (score 2):

Let $ O = (0, 0)$, $ E = (x,y)$ .

We have

- $AE^2  = (4+r)^2 = (4+x)^2 + (0+y)^2 $
- $OE^2 = (4-r)^2 = (0+x)^2 + (0+y)^2 $

By symmetry, one can observe that $ y = \frac{4}{2} = 2$.
Note: If you don't want the symmetry argument, then use
$TE^2 = (4-r)^2 = (0+x)^2 + (4 - y)^2 $ from which we get $ y = 2$.

Solve this system (EG Show $ x = 2r -2 $, and substitute back) to show that $ r = \sqrt{8/3}$.